# nodejs pm2 error on app startup

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I am trying to run a nodejs application I built on my windows machine unto my Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I have installed nodejs and pm2 hovewer when I try to start the pm2's web interface using `pm2 web` or start my nodejs app using `pm2 start myapp.js`, it throws this error: `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is nodejs installed? I'd recommend the use of [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: duplicate of a question asked later in time:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281057/node-forever-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 21):

You must run following command in console:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

and try again to run the node app.