# Node forever /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, forever

I have installed nodejs using:

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

Then i have installed npm using:

```
apt-get install npm
```

And then i have installed forever using:

```
npm install forever -g
```

Now i go to my project `/var/www/myproject`

and attempt to run `forever start server.js`

then i get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install NodeJs: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I get this bug and I am using Node Version Manager.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

EDIT: As of December 2018, this is no longer the correct way. See the other two answers.

> You need to symlink the nodejs executable to node `sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/local/bin/node` The reason for this is that when you do "apt-get install node", it installs an unrelated package, so they had to choose a different name so it wouldn't conflict

Comment: what is $(which nodejs)" is the code you paste something i should just copy paste or?

Comment: "$(which nodejs)" gets the path of the nodejs executable. When you put something inside of "$()" it gets executed and then inserted into the containing command

Comment: @chedabob I have faced the same problem but I had not yet resolved it  when I am running your command at that time   I got the                         ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/node’: File exists

Comment: @dasadiya-chaitanya In that case make sure that the existing file is pointing to a correct node executable by running the following. ls -lart /usr/bin/node. If the symlink is not pointing to the correct binary, in that case delete it. And re-run the following: sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node

Comment: @brownmamba I have fixed it from my side but not going with your way but finally thanks

Comment: On Debian and Ubuntu, there is a package `nodejs-legacy` providing the symbolic link. You're not supposed to do it manually. `apt-get install nodejs-legacy` is the correct way to fix the problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 44):

While the accepted answer fixes the problem, the correct way to do that, at least with Debian Jessie and forward and Ubuntu 14.4 and forward[1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nodejs-legacy) is to install **nodejs-legacy**:

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

The reason is that Debian already had a package (node) providing */usr/bin/node*, and the nodejs *node* binary had to be installed into /usr/bin/nodejs.

The **nodejs-legacy** package provides a symbolic link from /usr/bin/nodejs to /usr/bin/node (and conflicts with the **node** package).

Source: [[CTTE #614907] Resolution of node/nodejs conflict](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html) and [Debian bug #614907: node: name conflicts with node.js interpreter](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614907)

Comment: This is the correct way on Debian/Ubuntu +1, great context for those not familiar with the OS.

Comment: this broke npm completely `SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`, even uninstalling legacy and reinstalling npm throws the same error.

Comment: continuing my last comment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125173/2131849) fixed what the current answer broke, and I was able to continue with the answer provided by @Shantanu

Comment: do not do this please, it will break your npm install

Answer (score 22):

It's better if you update to the latest node version

1. sudo npm cache clean -f
2. sudo npm install -g n
3. sudo n stable