# PM2 inside bash script deployed and executed with puppet not working

Tags: node.js, bash, puppet, pm2

```
    #!/bin/bash
    yum -y install gcc-c++
    wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
    tar -xvzf  node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
    cd node-v0.12.7
    ./configure
     make
     sudo make install
     yum -y install git
    /usr/local/bin/npm install pm2 -g
    cd /home/admin/Order-Management/
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start processes.json
```

The above script run perfectly when I run it locally but when I try to execute it with puppet on the client machine the last line throwing the following error.

```
    /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I am using RedHat 6 master and RedHat 6 client. I saw a solution here 
[Node forever /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281057/node-forever-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-director) However not working for me. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `node` binary on your system? Is it `/usr/local/bin/node`?

Comment: yes I have it and in the same place u mentioned.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/node` a binary or a script? If it is a script what does its first line say? Does a new terminal session work?

Comment: It is a binary. What do u mean by new terminal session I did not get it ?

Comment: I mean start a new terminal window/shell session and try running `pm2`. Does it work? Can you run `/usr/local/bin/node` manually? Can you run `/usr/bin/env node` manually?

Comment: I have solved it. I had to add environment variable for puppet exec resource. That was not a problem for node.

Comment: If you have a solution that is meaningful then you should write it up as an answer and accept it. If not you should probably delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add environment variable for puppet exec resource. That was not a problem for node.