# 'node --no-deprecation': No such file or directory when running global npm command in ubuntu docker container

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the npm package [@stoplight/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stoplight/cli) globally onto a docker image for use in a GitHub action. The docker image builds successfully, but when I call stoplight from /bin/bash with `stoplight`, I get the dreaded `/usr/bin/env: 'node --no-deprecation': No such file or directory` error.

I know there has been a lot of questions of this exact error, but so far none of the solutions have worked<sup>[1](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911)</sup><sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281057/node-forever-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)</sup>.

I tried:

- Creating symlink with ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
- Installing nodejs-legacy instead

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install git curl
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g @stoplight/cli@3.0.1

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "stoplight --version"]
```

EDIT: ** I also tried doing this with the official debian "node" image as base, and it was the same issue.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we've released a new version of the CLI that should hopefully resolve the issue for you. The following dockerfile should work!

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g @stoplight/cli@3.0.4

ENTRYPOINT ["stoplight"]
```